# Django - ImportError: No module named apps

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am trying out the Django tutorial on the djangoproject.com website, but when I reach the part where I do the first "makemigrations polls" I keep getting this error:

> ImportError: No module named apps

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What version of Django do you have installed?

Comment: I get this when I type `python -m django --version` : /usr/bin/python: No module named django.__main__; 'django' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: Be sure you install django correctly.

Comment: show us your catalog structure, and your settings.py file

Comment: uninstall and Install Django properly.

Comment: `python -m django --version` will work for Django 1.9+. For earlier versions, you can do `python -c 'import django; print(django.VERSION)'`

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that your Django version does not match the version of the tutorial.

In Django 1.9+, the startapp command automatically creates an app config class, so [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) asks you to add `polls.apps.PollsConfig` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

For Django 1.8 and earlier, [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models) asks you to add `polls` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you add `polls.apps.PollsConfig` instead, you will get an import error, unless you create the `PollsConfig` manually.

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in the tutorial.

It instructs to add `polls.apps.PollsConfig` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of the `settings.py` file. I changed it from `polls.apps.PollsConfig` to simply `polls` and that did the trick. I was able to successfully make migrations.

I hope this helps other people who face similar problems.

Comment: I don't think there's an error in the tutorial, the problem is that you were following the wrong version of the tutorial.

Comment: Any idea why this solution worked, because it worked for me too.

Answer (score 5):

I had a really **similar issue**, but one that was definitely **different than the OP**. That said, this post was one of the first responses I found when debugging my issue, so I'm hijacking it with an answer to my question.

#### Problem

The app I was building had apps nested beneath a parent namespace, e.g. `customapp.polls` instead of just `polls`. The error I saw was

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls'
```

but probably looks like the following if you're on Python 3.5 or older:

```
ImportError: No module named polls
```

Note that this says `polls` instead of `apps` in the original post.

#### Answers from this post

- @Alasdair's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537343/260303) is a good one to try. If I force a similar issue, I get an error about `customapp.polls.apps.PollsConfig` and `customapp.polls.apps` being missing instead of `apps`, but that could just be differences in versions.
- @Monil's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537105/260303) "solved" my issue, even though I had a `PollsConfig` subclass defined. As @Alasdair suggests, the reason that works is often because you didn't add an `AppConfig` subclass.

#### Solution

In my case, the error complained about the `polls` module being missing (not `apps`). And since @Monils [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537105/260303) "solved" my issue, I was able to narrow it down to my actual configuration. My config looked equivalent to:

```
class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'
```

**but** since I put my apps underneath a parent module, I should have written:

```
class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'customapp.polls'
```

Comment: THIS. Works for Django 2.0+. Should be noted that the entry in customapp/settings.py should have the installed app named also changed from 'polls' to 'customapp.polls.' Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install required packages in your virtualenv to run Django project. First and foremost create virtualenv for your project.

```
virtualenv env    #For python 2.7
virtualenv -p python3 env #For python 3.4
```

Actiavte env to install your requirements.

```
source env/bin/activate
```

By using pip you can then install your packages.

```
pip install Django
```

And then start your Django project.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.10.6 I had the same error ("no module named..."). The solution that worked for me is changing `"polls.apps.PollsConfig"` for `"mysite.polls"` in `settings.py`. o.O

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for me. When you write `polls.apps.PollsConfig` in your `InstalledApps`, you need to have in mind that, the first `polls` refers to the created app, not to the site.
In the Django documentation it can be a bit confusing.